# Basic String.match not matching

Tags: java, regex

Java's `String.match` is not behaving the way I think it should and I'm not sure why.  Here is what I'm doing, I'm trying to parse the subdomain of a host and do something conditionally if the subdomain matches "dev".

```
String serverName = httpServletRequest.getServerName();
    List<String> partsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(serverName.split("\\.")));
    if(partsList.size() == 3) {
        String subDomain = partsList.get(0);
        System.out.println(subDomain + " => " + subDomain.matches("dev"));
```

The thing is, this prints the following to the console:

```
dev01 => false
```

What is going on here?  It clearly does match.  Am I using the regex string incorrectly?

Comment: `Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.`. Does `"dev01"` match the full regex `"dev"`?

Comment: You might be looking for `String#contains(String)`.

Comment: Edgar, "dev01".  Sotirios, I think its the other way around right, dev01 should match "dev" "^dev" and "^dev\d+", no?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I want to expand this to dev or qa as in `subDomain.matches("^(?:dev|qa)")`

Comment: The match should be _anything_ followed by `dev` followed by _anything_.

Comment: Why are you using regex at all here? Just startsWith() or equals().

Comment: Guys, good points, sorry I didn't understand that `matches` matches the whole string.  I was thinking of the more general matcher object as in  `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.matches()` matches the **whole** String

I recommend `String.startsWith()`.

Answer (score 3):

May I recommend a simpler solution?

```
subDomain.contains("dev")
```

Comment: Thats good too, though the first thing I need to do is expand it to starts with dev or qa